# Nginx doesn't work, no permissions rights and can't find some dir

Tags: nginx

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. I've installed Nginx and configured it with ISPConfig. 
Then, I wanted to install the passenger module. Because Nginx doesn't allow dynamic modules, I had it compiled from source.

First, I uninstalled Nginx (with `apt-get remove --purge nginx nginx-full nginx-common`) and started a new Nginx installation. I then used passenger advanced mod where I added some directives to `.configure` option as it was installed via `apt-get` (`/usr/share..`, `/etc/nginx`, `/var/log` location etc..)

NOTE: I grabbed the compile info from `nginx -V`). It successfully installed and then I ran the command:

```
root@webserver:/# /usr/share/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

but it throws this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/lib/nginx/body" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

What's wrong?

I didn't believe the solution would be so simple because I've been playing with it all day; `mkdir nginx` does work.

Comment: If you've solved your issue please write it up as an answer to your own question and then accept it.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I created new directories:

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx
mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/body
mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/fastcgi
```

That worked for me.

Comment: bash oneliner: `mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/{body,fastcgi}`

Answer (score 0):

I had to do all this:

```
mkdir  --parents  /var/lib/nginx/body
mkdir  --parents  /var/lib/nginx/fastcgi
mkdir  --parents  /var/lib/nginx/proxy
mkdir  --parents  /var/lib/nginx/uwsgi
mkdir  --parents  /var/lib/nginx/scgi
chown  --recursive  www-data  /var/lib/nginx
```